# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement haiku

Tags: python, installation, error-handling, pip, package

Could anyone please help me fix the following error after running `pip install haiku`?

```
"ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement haiku (from versions: 0.01_20110820-135621)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for haiku"
```

Thank you so much for any helpful answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After read documentation about haiku https://dm-haiku.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

the document suggest to install with this code

```
pip install git+https://github.com/deepmind/dm-haiku
```